# «Серебряный век»: какая буква?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Моей учительнице по литературе больше нравится Серебряный век, чем Бронзовый.

> Моей учительнице по литературе больше нравится серебряный век, чем бронзовый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С этим вопросом всё крайне сложно, так как есть оба варианта + вариант с кавычками.

На эту тему есть целая статья.

> [https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/serebryanyy-vek-vymysel-umysel-ili-realnost-zamechaniya-k-neokonchennomu-sporu-o-terminah#:~:text=Если%20под%20Серебряным%20веком%20подразумевается,невозможно%20не%20разделить%20мнения%20Л](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/serebryanyy-vek-vymysel-umysel-ili-realnost-zamechaniya-k-neokonchennomu-sporu-o-terminah#:%7E:text=%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F,%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%9B).

По большей части, решение остаётся за автором, как много он в это вкладывает. Как по мне, если мы пишем "античность" со строчной (маленькой), то нет причин другие периоды писать как-то иначе.